# How to click RibbonMenuButton .Net

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ribbon

how can I click RibbomMenuItem? I have xaml code

```
<Custom:RibbonMenuButton Name="bt1" Label="Stop"/>
```

but I can't use Click property to run background function write in .cs file. How can I handle Click event for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RibbonMenuButton` dont have `Click` event.
Use `MouseLeftButtonDown` of `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` instead.

```
<Custom:RibbonMenuButton MouseLeftButtonDown="b_MouseLeftButtonDown" Name="bt1" Label="Stop"/>
```

In the code:

```
void b_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: It's not working on my side. I've added MessageBox.Show("Test"); into function and its not trigerred.

Comment: Does change to `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` solve the problem?

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot! :)